# What parts are usually changed when the timing belt is replaced?

Tags: scheduled-maintenance, timing-belt, water-pump

When changing a timing belt, what other parts are:

1. Always changed with it ( as in they always have to be replaced ) ?
2. Often, but not always changed with it ( depending on how worn they are )?

For example, my mechanic said he would also inspect the water pump and might have to replace that also.

I'm not sure if this can be answered in general, or I need to relate this to a specific vehicle.

Comment: I agree with the water pump recommendation. However, water pumps –particularly rebuilt ones- have a small but worrisome tendency towards infant mortality, i.e. the failure rate is initially higher. Higher quality is a good investment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Obviously the timing belt needs to be replaced. Then they could change any followers or guides which mechanically get worn out. I would *always* recommend getting the water pump changed if it is driven off of the belt, or located in the same vicinity as the belt. The reason for this is, if you have to remove everything to replace the pump (ie: timing cover, belt, followers, re-time the camshaft(s), etc) to do the work, if the pump were to go out at another time, you'll end up spending for a second round of labor to get it replaced. Labor is the biggest part of the bill on doing the timing belt. In most cases, it is literally five to ten more minutes of work to replace the pump. Most timing belt kits come with a water pump. The cost of most of them are very incidental to the overall cost of getting the timing belt replace. For peace of mind sake, just do the pump at the same time. You could view changing the water pump as pro-active maintenance as you're doing it before it fails.

Comment: What are the follower or guides?  Do all these things usually come in a timing belt kit?  Is OEM recommended on something like this or are cheaper third party parts usually OK?

Comment: @RobertS.Barnes ... If it needs changed for any particular vehicle, it will usually come in the kit. For any vehicle you are considering doing the work on, become completely fluent in how it's done prior to attempting it. This will give you the best idea whether you can even do it, as well as all of the parts involved. There are vehicles like a lot of Jaguars which I wouldn't even attempt (though it has chains instead of belts). With them, if you get one thing wrong, it will lunch the entire engine.

Comment: Also, to answer your question ... a follower is (probably my term) for the part which can take up slack in the belt. The guides are usually nylon or plastic pieces which keeps the belt in the right position while the engine is running. It can go either way with OEM or OEM equivalent. Both should work just fine while there probably isn't that big of a price difference. Just don't buy an OEM at the dealer ... get it online somewhere for the best pricing.

Comment: @rhill45 which gasket ?

Comment: Good time to change the head gasket and check your cylinders

Comment: The two things on your engine you REALLY don't want to break are the timing belt and water pump.When the timing belt goes, it usually takes your valves (ans sometimes your pistons and rods) with it. When the waterpump fails, the engine overheats and blows a headgasket. That means you'll be paying for a new headgasket PLUS a timing belt job (because you have to remove the timing belt to remove the head).

Comment: A waterpump costs a couple of whatever currency you have, the damage from a broken waterpump costs about as much as giving birth in a hospital without the benefit of medical aid.

Comment: @rhill45 ... ummm ... You should never pull the head unless the gasket is blown or you are rebuilding the engine. This falls under the adage *if it ain't broke don't fix it*.

Comment: @Paulster2 "a follower is (probably my term) for the part which can take up slack in the belt." That's usually referred to as a tensioner in all the cars I have dealt with...

Comment: If I suspect that the source of burning oil ( about a liter a month / per 1800 kilometers ) is the valve gaskets, would this be an opportune time to change them ( ie less expensive than doing it separately ).

Comment: @RobertS.Barnes ... depending on the engine, the valve cover may/may not need to come off of the engine. Usually a valve cover gasket is a fairly easy repair task and can be done at any time independent of the timing belt (true on most engines). Cost would be separate and usually added to the cost of changing the timing belt.

Comment: Don't forget cam and crank oil seals while you're in there, too. Another thing you'd have to do the whole job over again for. @RobertS.Barnes

Answer (score 2):

Timing belt, timing belt tensioner, spark plugs and maybe spark plug wires, water pump, thermostat and all other belts. I also at that time drain my transmission fluid (not flush).

Answer (score 1):

The alternator belt. When it shreds it can entwine with the timing belt. Bend valves and require a head skim. Very expensive. Or terminal.